# What's the best way to remind users which OpenID provider they used to sign up with?

Tags: openid

When designing a web app that offers support for multiple OpenID providers to users when they  sign up, what's the best way to help the user remember which OpenID provider they signed up with?  How would you simplify the process when they return to your site?

Answer (score 0):

Store a cookie with the provider's name and pre-select the provider with the value from the cookie. [openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) does it that way.